# Export Nvarchar Datatype to CSV

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion, export-to-csv, coldfusion-10, nvarchar

I'm attempting to export international characters from query to csv. Output to the browser works fine, as does writing to Excel using CFSPREADSHEET.

I have the following set up:

- The datasource connection uses JDBC
- Table fields are nvarchar

Rendering the file is as follows:

```
<cfset filepath="c:/test.csv" />
<cfloop query="q">
  <cfset string = "" />
  <cfset string = listAppend(string, q.fieldname) />
  <cffile action="append" file="#filePath#" output="#string#" charset="windows-1252" />
</cfloop>
<cffile action="readbinary" file="#filePath#" variable="bin" charset="windows-1252"> 
<cffile action="delete" file="#filePath#" /> 
<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="attachment; filename=Output.csv" charset="windows-1252"> 
<cfcontent type="text/plain" reset="true" variable="#bin#" />
```

However, certain characters are not converting properly. For example:

- Jørgen shows as JÃ¸rgen
- Sälzler shows as SÃ¤lzler

Update - Adding `charset="windows-1252"` did solve a majority of the bad conversions including the above examples.  The following still do not convert

- Krčobić shows Kr?obi?
- Mirosław shows Miro?aw
- Bożek shows Bo?ek

Comment: The `cffile` tags writes to the file using the default character set of the JVM (can be set in cfadmin). Try using the charset attribute like `charset="windows-1252`

Comment: That solved a majority of the characters! The name, for example, Krčobić still shows `Kr?obi?`

Comment: Did you try [adding a BOM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47360000/8895292)? Worked for me with Krčobić.